# The Constant in Integration

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

I have a rudimentary understanding of calculus and  I know that if $y = f(x) = 2x + 3$ then, $\frac{dy}{dx} = 2$ and now if I were to perform the inverse operation, integration, $\int 2 dx = 2x + C$ where $C$ is called the *constant of integration*.

As a *definite integral* (?), pardon my ignorance, $\int_1^2 2 dx$, I get $(2(2) + C) - (2(1) + C) = 2$ . It is *not necessary* to know what $C$ is. However, what about, if $g(x) = \int 2 dx$, $g(0)$? $g(0) = C$ but we *can't know* $C$.

Comment: If all you know about $a$ is that $a^2=4$, then you can't know the sign of $a$. But you can compute that $a^4$ is $16$. If $g(x)=\int 2dx$, then all you know about $g$ is that $g'(x)=2$, and that does not uniquely determine the value of $g$ at $0$, but you can use it to compute your definite integral. So yes, what you've said is correct. Did you have some further question?

Comment: Is it not important to know $C$ (the constant of integration)? The derivative of a constant is $0$ and so a function $y = f(x) = 4$ would have a slope/derivative = $0$. I now *can't* integrate to $y = f(x) = 4$. Notice this is different from $a^2 = 4$ where $a = \pm 2$.

Comment: Generally it is not important to know the constant of integration. And, more importantly, it is not possible to uniquely determine it - two different people using different methods to compute an indefinite integral might come up with different values of the constant.

Comment: It sounds like you understand what's going on: the antiderivative is not unique, it's only unique up to addition of a constant. What's your question?

Comment: @Karl, has no one tried to work on the problem. It would be nice, *cogito*, if we could find out the correct $C$. Can we perhaps *guesstimate* it? For example if $y = f(x) = F - 0.5x$, where $y$ is the amount of fuel left in the gas tank after travelling $x$ miles, the constant of integration would be $F$ and we know that gas tanks have a maximum capacity of $200$ gallons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $+C$ at the end of the indefinite integral $\int f dx = F(x) + C$ represents the fact that for any integrable function $f$ there are *infinitely many* valid antiderivatives. In fact, they form an [equivalence class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_class), and the notation $\int f dx$ represents this class while $F(x) + C$ represents a *generic* member of the class.

By that measure, it's not wrong to write $\int 2x\ dx = x^2 + 3 + C$, for example. After all, $G(x) = x^2 + 3$ is as much an antiderivative of $2x$ as $F(x) = x^2$ is, and any valid antiderivative can be written as $G(x) + C$ for some value of $C$. We just tend to choose the simplest (for some definition of simple) antiderivative to represent the whole class as a matter of convention. (It also means that if you use two different methods to integrate a function $f$ and you come up with two different solutions, it is entirely possible that it's because the difference between those solutions is just a constant.)

When we calculate a definite integral via the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, it doesn't matter *which* antiderivative of $f$ we choose, it only matters that we choose the same one at both bounds of integration, which is why the constant $C$ vanishes.

(There are some details I've left out here, e.g. an assumption about the region that $f$ is integrable over, but hopefully this provides some basis for understanding.)

Comment: Would I be correct if I were to say that what we don't know about the *antiderivative* is the *shift* along the $y$ axis or the $y$ intercept?

Comment: Broadly, yes. When you get past plain differentiation and integration into differential equations, though, you will come across similar families of functions where the parameter(s) that separate elements aren't just an added constant. For example, while the equation $\frac{dy}{dx} = -x$ has the solution set $\{-\frac{x^2}{2} + C\}$, the equation $\frac{dy}{dx} = -y$ has the solution set $\{Ce^{-x}\}$.